# Angular - Loop through unique items from REST data

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-directive

I am trying to iterate through unique "modules" that are received through REST services. There are multiple href's that are associated with a single module.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var moduleServiceUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/Items?$select=ID,Title,FileRef,Modules";
        var appVar = angular.module('listApp', []);

        appVar.controller('controller1', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: moduleServiceUrl,
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.items = data.d.results;

            });
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <hr />
    <div ng-app="listApp">
        <div id="App1" ng-controller="controller1">
            <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="item.Modules">
                <b><p>{{item.Modules}}</p></b>
                <p class="kbRelatedArticle" style="padding-left:10px"><a href="{{item.FileRef}}">{{item.Title}}</a></p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Here is what the current output looks like]

My goal is to have all the links under the same module heading instead of having repeated module headings.

My initial thought was to have a nested ng-repeat in which the outer ng-repeat would loop through the unique modules and the inner would then generate the links that are related to that module.

Comment: Are you against using a utility library like Lodash? If not, see https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#groupBy

Comment: Note that you're using the deprecated `$http` `success()` callback ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object with `Modules` as the key and an array of items as the value like so

```
$scope.modules = data.d.results.reduce((modules, item) => {
    if (item.Modules) {
        if (Array.isArray(modules[item.Modules])) {
            modules[item.Modules].push(item);
        } else {
            modules[item.Modules] = [item];
        }
    }
    return modules;
}, Object.create(null));
```

Or if you're not against using something like Lodash

```
$scope.modules = _.groupBy(data.d.results, 'Modules');
```

Then your HTML can use a nested repeater

```
<div ng-repeat="(module, items) in modules">
    <p><strong>{{module}}</strong></p>
    <p ng-repeat="item in items" style="padding-left:10px;">
        <a ng-href="{{item.FileRef}}">{{item.Title}}</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, just tested this solution and it seems to produce the desired results.